# Quantiles in ols/cph

Tags: r, quantiles, regression-strategies, rms

I need to conduct regression analyses with continuous and categorised data (as the latter is common in my field). So far, I used to do this as follows:

```
q <- lm(ep ~ cut2(exposure, g=5), data=data)
```

When I use the functions in the `rms` package, this doesn't seem to work:

```
q <- ols(ep ~ cut2(exposure, g=5), data=data)
```

and results in an error message (subscript out of bounds). It does work fine if I pre-define the quantiles, but this causes problems in the scripts I use.

Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rms` package wants you to handle complex transformations by creating a new variable in your data frame.  Although simple transformations are handled in-line (e.g., log(x)), you'll need to create a variable for the result of `cut2`.

Comment: Thank you! Would I do the same when using `fit.mult.impute`, i.e. create the quintiles before imputation (and analysis)?

Comment: Yes.  But note that analyzing quintiles of a continuous variable is not really valid - it leads to misleading estimates and inefficiency.  Use this approach only for educational purposes.  This should **never** be the primary analysis.

Comment: Unfortunately using quintiles is so common that reviewers will probably not accept not having them. But I will try.

Comment: I've never had a paper rejected to used only continuous analyses.  The quantile approach is wrong on so many levels.  Just to mention two: the outer quintiles will be very heterogeneous, and the definition of your variable will come from sample demographics and have nothing to do with the intrinsic meaning of the variable.  It's a lose-lose situation.  See my BBR and RMS notes and checklist for authors [here](http://fharrell.com/links) for more information.

Comment: I agree completely - but you're well known and respected, with considerable experience and expertise.

I haven't found any paper in a mainstream journal of my field (nutrition), where quantiles were not the main results (and perhaps a spline-figure to accompany it). Most readers are used to quantiles and many would struggle to interpret splines (which would not give the same "accurate" numbers to interpret).

Comment: Splines are actually much easier to interpret and don't assume piecewise flat relationships.  You can explain this as "I did a test of goodness of fit of the model to the data and the quintile approach failed the test".  Also tell the editor that how many friends and neighbors who are like you is not what predicts your outcomes; it's YOUR weight.